# Python/Kivy: Manual settings page - actualize text size in .kv-file

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to implement a manually created settings page in my Kivy app. In this context, I am experiencing problems in using actualized settings inside of the app. To demonstrate the problem, please use this minimal example:

Python file "main.py", in which I am trying to write the current font size in the two global variables first_size and second_size, which in turn I would like to access in the Kivy file lateron:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from settingsjson import settings_json
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

import settings

class MainMenu(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("style.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global first_size, second_size
        first_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["first_label"])
        second_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["second_label"])
        return presentation

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('settings', {
            'test_size': settings.options[0]
            })

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Own Settings',
                                self.config,
                                data=settings_json)

    def reset_labels(self, first_labelsize, second_labelsize):
        global first_size, second_size
        first_size = NumericProperty(first_labelsize)
        second_size = NumericProperty(second_labelsize)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        first_labelsize = settings.sizes[value]['first_label']
        second_labelsize = settings.sizes[value]['second_label']
        self.reset_labels(first_labelsize, second_labelsize)

myApp = MyApp()
myApp.run()
```

Python file "settingsjson.py", containing the new settings page:

```
import json
import settings

settings_json = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Settings'},
    {'type': 'options',
     'title': 'Size',
     'desc': 'Test size',
     'options': settings.options,
     'section': 'settings',
     'key': 'test_size'}])
```

Python-file "settings.py" for a dictionary associating the two options in the settings menu with font sizes:

```
options = ['small', 'large']

small = {'first_label': 20, 'second_label': 15}
large = {'first_label': 30, 'second_label': 25}

sizes = {options[0]: small, options[1]: large}
```

And finally the Kivy file "style.kv":

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainMenu:

## accessing first global variable (not working)
<Button>:
    font_size: root.first_size

## accessing second global variable (not working either)
<TwoLineButton@Button>:
    font_size: root.second_size


<MainMenu>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "right": 1}
            text: "One-line dummy"
        TwoLineButton:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "left": 1}
            text: "This is a two-line\n dummy"
            halign: "center"

        Button:
            on_release:
                app.open_settings()
            text: "Settings"
            font_size: self.height/4
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.1, "right": 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
```

As you can see, the current form of the code is not working, because the I can't access the two font size variables in the Kivy file. If I set the font_size properties in the Kivy file to constant values, the app runs without problems, but of course doesn't allow for the changes in the settings menu to take effect.

Is there a way to access the global variables in the main.py-file in the Kivy file to reset the font size of the two types of button?

As I have to change the settings in more than just one screen, I need a global class-independent solution.

I am grateful for every kind of hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach using the on_ callback to automatically change the font size when the numeric properties are changed. Note that first_size and second_size must be defined before loading style.kv

Main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from settingsjson import settings_json
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

import settings

class MainMenu(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    first_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["first_label"])
    second_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["second_label"])

    def on_first_size(self, instance, value):
        self.main_menu.ids['button1'].font_size = value

    def on_second_size(self, instance, value):
        self.main_menu.ids['button2'].font_size = value

    def build(self):
        presentation = Builder.load_file("style.kv")
        self.main_menu = presentation.current_screen
        return presentation

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('settings', {
        'test_size': settings.options[0]
        })

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Own Settings',
                            self.config,
                            data=settings_json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        self.first_size = settings.sizes[value]['first_label']
        self.second_size = settings.sizes[value]['second_label']

myApp = MyApp()
myApp.run()
```

and style.kv:

```
ScreenManagement:
MainMenu:

<MainMenu>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: button1
            font_size: app.first_size
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "right": 1}
            text: "One-line dummy"
        Button:
            id: button2
            font_size: app.second_size
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "left": 1}
            text: "This is a two-line\n dummy"
            halign: "center"

        Button:
            on_release:
                app.open_settings()
            text: "Settings"
            font_size: self.height/4
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.1, "right": 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the on_first_size() and on_second_size() functions. They can be deleted.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! This helped a lot! I have three more specific follow-up questions:

1) It seems that the app saves the size setting selection ('large', 'small') when shutting down for the next start. However, as the first_size and second_size variables are manually defaulted when starting the app, the selection and the actual text size sometimes don't match. Is there a way to directly access saved information from the last app start in a "try (use settings from last time) ... except (use default settings)" for the two variables?

Comment: 2) Is there a way to reset the titles of the "Cancel" and "Close" buttons in the settings menu, e.g. to translate them to a different language?

Comment: 3) When changing settings in the standard menu (e.g., fullscreen mode or rotation), the changes only apply when manually restarting the app. How can I automatically initiate a restart upon changes or directly apply the changed settings without restarting?

Comment: For question1, in your build() method, add:


`        text_size = self.config['settings']['test_size']

        self.first_size = settings.sizes[text_size]["first_label"]

        self.second_size = settings.sizes[text_size]["second_label"]`


before the call to Builder.load(). This also means that your creation of the NumericProperties can be just 'NumericProperty(0)'.

Comment: For question 3, change your on_config_change() method to:


`    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        if section == 'settings':
            self.first_size = settings.sizes[value]['first_label']
            self.second_size = settings.sizes[value]['second_label']
        else:
            #restart to make these changes take effect
            # check section and key to determine if restart is desired
            pid = os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, sys.executable, sys.executable, sys.argv[0])
            self.stop()`

Comment: Sorry for the way the above comments look, but I cannot make sense of the formatting rules for comments :-(

Comment: For question 2, I have no experience in this area, but I would refer you to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gettext.html

Comment: Thanks again! Once again, your hints were really helpful! Your answer on question 1 runs perfectly fine!

Unfortunately, when modifying the 'on_config_change()' method according to your suggestion on question 3, the app closes, but doesn't restart. I tried adding
'myApp = MyApp()' and 'myApp.run()' into the method, but this doesn't really work - it seemed to open 3 instead of 1 instance of the app, neither of which showed the altered settings (Fullscreen mode in my test). I also tried 'MyApp.build()', which showed no effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned. The restart will not work if you are running the app inside an IDE (like PyCharm).

Comment: I see! Thanks again for taking the time! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but in the .kv file eliminate your Button and TwoLineButton definitions and access the root.first_size and root.second_size from your actual Button definitions in the layout:

```
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        font_size: root.first_size
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "right": 1}
        text: "One-line dummy"
    Button:
        font_size: root.second_size
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.5, "left": 1}
        text: "This is a two-line\n dummy"
        halign: "center"
```

The "root" it is referencing is the "MainMenu", so add class level variables "first_size" and "second_size" in your MainMenu class:

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
    first_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["first_label"])
    second_size = NumericProperty(settings.sizes[settings.options[0]]["second_label"])
```

Since these are not instance variables, you can reference them as "MainMenu.first_size" and "MainMenu.second_size" from anywhere you import MainMenu.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work for me... the font sizes remain constant, since the "refresh" action of the MyApp class only affects this class. I somehow need to be able to access a "get_setting" method from the MyApp class to figure out, which setting is currently active...

However, maybe I didn't understand you correctly... could you elaborate on your solution?